# What are the elements of the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z^{*}_{15}$?

Tags: encryption

> [image]

What are the elements of the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z^{*}_{15}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$$

The multiplicative group $\mathbb Z^*_n$ is the subset of $\mathbb Z_n$ which only contains elements with a multiplicative inverse (i.e. for which you can find another number such that when multiplied together they yield 1). This criterion happens to be equivalent to "exclude the $0$ and all $x$ with $\gcd(x,n)>1$" where $\gcd$ is the greatest-common-divisor function.

Comment: Yes. In that group, the law (noted $*$ ) defined by: _take the product then keep the remainder of the euclidean division of that product by $15$_ is internal, associative and commutative, the neutral element is $1$, and every element $x$ has an opposite/inverse $y$ such that $x*y=1$ . For example, $8*11$ is $13$, because the product of $8$ and $11$ is $88$, and the remainder of the Euclidean division of $88$ by $15$ is $13$ [the quotient of the division is $5$, and $13=88-(15\times5)$ ]. And the inverse of  $7$ is $13$, because similarly $7*13=1$.